# Count of type for each week of a month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have data like below

--date--------- Type

> 6/1/2014
>
> 6/2/2014   -ss
>
> 6/3/2014   -pp
>
> 6/4/2014   -PP
>
> 6/5/2014   -ss
>
> 6/6/2014   -pp
>
> 6/7/2014
>   6/8/2014
>
> 6/9/2014   pp
>
> 6/10/2014  PP
>
> 6/11/2014  ss
>
> 6/12/2014  pp
>
> 6/13/2014  PP
>
> 6/14/2014
>   6/15/2014
>
> And Result should be like this

------6/2/2014 to 6/6/2014 ----------   6/9/2014 to 6/13/2014

> ss ------2 ---------------------------------1
>
> pp ------3 ---------------------------------4

Comment: what's the data type of the date column?

Comment: Column names cannot be dynamic in SQL.  If you want a query that will work on an arbitrary month, then you would need to use dynamic SQL.  (I would recommend have the structure of date range, type, count instead.)

Comment: Date column date type is dattime @BrianDeMilia

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/937f0/6/0

```
select min(dt) as dt_from, max(dt) as dt_to, type, count(*) as num
from tbl
where type is not null
group by datepart(year, dt)+datepart(week, dt), type
order by 1
```

It is functionally equivalent to what you want, but each week is a row (not a column)

On a sidenote, the dt_from and dt_to is not necessarily the start/end of the week, if there is no data on the start/end of the week, but it is still grouped by week. If you want to show the week #, and year, you can add what I put into the group by clause to the select list and you'll get the year and week # in that column.

Also if you're never querying more than a 1 year timeframe you can just group by:

```
group by datepart(week, dt), type
```

The year is extracted in the first query to avoid week 12, 13, etc. of year 2013 being combined with week 12, 13, etc. of year 2014, in the event you were to query 2+ years of data. It is not needed if you always query within the same year (or month).